# List subcategories of a specific product category (adapting from posts to products taxonomy)

Tags: categories

I made the below for my sidebar to show the subcategories of a specific category (ID 89) of my choosing. Only the subcategories that the post is in appear. Works great.

Now I want to change my posts in to WooCommerce Products, so I'm trying to adapt the code to target WC subcategories instead of post categories. I'm a bit lost on where to start.

```
<ul>
    <?php foreach (get_the_category() as $childcat) : ?>
    <?php if (cat_is_ancestor_of(89, $childcat)) { ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo get_category_link($childcat->term_id); ?>"><?php echo $childcat->cat_name; ?></a>
        </li>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

> ...to show the subcategories of a specific category (ID 89)  ...

Try this

```
$product_cats = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
if ( ! empty( $product_cats ) && ! is_wp_error( $product_cats ) ) { ?>
<ul>
    <?php 
    foreach ($product_cats as $childcat) : ?>
    <?php if ($childcat->parent == 89)) { ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo get_term_link($childcat->term_id); ?>"><?php echo $childcat->name; ?></a>
        </li>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
<?php } ?>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hmmm, the second line is breaking my site. But I see where this is going now; I'm going to tinker with it. Thanks !!

Comment: @SeanAUS120 Answer updated. There was a missing  `}` after  `</ul>` at the end of code which I forgot to format as part of code block and consequentle WPSE did not rendered it.